# Volume control in OS X has no effect

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

My volume in OS X doesn't seem to be actually controlling my volume. Not that the displayed "output volume" in the Sound preference pane doesn't change as I press volume up and volume down keys. The overlay changes, but the actual volume (the little boops) pushed through the headphones and the displayed volume in the preference pane don't change.

Shortly after taking these images, I lost all sound control via the keys. It just shows a muted overlay. The only way I could change the volume is via the sound preference pane now.

After a few minutes, I spontaneously regained control of volume via the keys. This has been happening on and off for the past week. What is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Batteries of the keyboard are ok? Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: reboot ^ (or relaunch coreaudiod)

Comment: @patrix The keyboard is the laptop keyboard. Also, the overlay *does* respond to the keys. It's just the actual volume does not. The problem goes away immediately after a reboot but returns later on.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX If that is the solution, please write it as an answer. Why would I need to manually do this? Is this a bug or known issue?

Comment: For future reference, press <kbd>space</kbd> after pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd3>3</kbd>, to go into a mode which automatically detects UI elements. It makes for nicer screenshots :)

Comment: I'm just having the same issue on my MBP. Did you resolve the issue since then? Would it be a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting or relaunching the process `coreaudiod`. This is a glitch that often results from 3rd party programs, but occasionally coreaudiod will mess up on its own.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: Does first hand observation count?

Comment: Maybe.. How many times has this worked for you? How do you know that this is a result of 3rd party programs? How do you know that occasionally, coraudiod messes up on its own?

Comment: 1) everytime 2) i've isolated it to be caused by my USB speaker driver on my iMac 3) because I occasionally get it regardless of current apps running on my MacBook

Comment: I can confirm that development with Xcode involving audio can cause strange behaviour such as this. Thanks for the solution!